# Where are Profile Manager Configuration Profiles Stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, server.app, profile-manager

I ask because I configured and installed a profile for a network account on my Macbook Air (10.9) to create a synchronized Mobility Home on a Mac Mini server (10.8).

However, I cannot login as this user on the server or my Air, because I receive the message that the home already exists. This occurs even though I have removed the devices from profile manager and the user from the group.

I expect this is because I have not updated the configuration profile on the account, but I cannot do so because I cannot log in as that user.

So, I'd like to purge any instance of these configurations. So far, I've tried the following:

1. Deleting `/Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/`
2. Clearing the MCX Cache as per [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3540)

I am asking specifically how to clear these configs, but if it comes up, yes, I have deleted the home folder on the Air and the Mini, and no, neither have a local account with the same name.

Comment: Is it other users or one specific one? Can you delete and recreate the user?

Comment: The user did not show up in the user list in System Preferences or dscl, so I couldn't recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The profiles appear to be stored in

```
/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store/ConfigProfiles.binary
```

I'd not recommend tampering with it, though.

To see what profiles are installed, and then remove one, assuming you can sudo to the user, you could try:

```
root$ sudo -u chymb profiles -L
chymb[1] attribute: profileIdentifier: com.stackexchange.apple.test
There are 1 user configuration profiles installed for 'chymb'
root$ sudo -u chymb profiles -R -p com.stackexchange.apple.test
```

Comment: I ended up resolving it a different way (by fixing the problem that prevented the mobility home from being created), but this answers the question and is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't restricted System Preferences in the Profile Manager it should be an option in System Preferences > Profile.

Delete it from there and reboot.

Comment: I could not login as the user, so the profile did not appear there.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.